# Could not find stored procedure error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We transfer the database to a new server. New information upfront.

System returns an error :

> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find
>   stored procedure 'SlideList'.

But we are entering the old database information, system running smoothly.

What is the solution?

Comment: How exactly did you transfer/duplicate the database?  The `SqlException` suggests that you did so incompletely and are missing a stored procedure named `SlideList`.

Comment: make sure your database mapping and new connection should be correct then restart the IIS

Comment: Could the default database be master instead of something else it used to be and you're trying to call procedure from there?

Comment: make sure the user that is logging in has appropriate security/permissions

Comment: One option is, your new server is case sensitive, so the proc may be there, but it is referenced incorrectly.  Or as suggested above, it wasn't transferred.

Comment: The "Could not find stored procedure" error is often a red herring. Here's an example; open up SQL Server Mgmt Studio, and enter this into a query window: "SlideList" (include the quote marks). Then hit Execute. You'll get the error. When you have a string in quotes as your SQL statement, SQL Server defaults to assuming it is a stored procedure. Could it be some sort of quoting issue?